# Boost CMake cannot find python library

Tags: visual-studio-2012, boost, build, cmake

After sifting through the many other questions about CMake being unable to find boost libraries I still can't figure my issue out:

My Portion of the CMakeLists related to this:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mazeGen")
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mazeSolve")

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
```

when I specify `BOOST_ROOT` and try to build the project the error output is:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1111 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.55.0

  Boost include path: C:/local/boost_1_55_0

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_python

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:36 (find_package)
```

Where exactly should I point CMake in order to find the libraries? And how can I do this?

all of the built libraries are located in `${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib` and are built for VS2012, I tried setting `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` to `${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib` but this did nothing